# How do I send a get request from my Api to a Xamarin forms app?

Tags: python, c#, api, xamarin

Currently I am working on a Schoolproject and I need to send a Notification to a self written Xamarin Forms App from my API. It all runs on a local network and the App can already communicate with the Api, now i want my api to send a notification to my phone if a specific event turns true. How do I do this? (Oh and I am using Python flask for my API, if u need this Information)

Comment: An API can't send data to an app if the app doesn't calls the api, so basically (in a very dirty way but hey, it works) you could try to call your API every X minutes or seconds and make the api return false if there are no new notifications to display or true if there are some along with the notification text. Just remember to update this event status to something like "already displayed" so you won't get it as a new event everytime you call your api

Answer (score 0):

- Use Push notification for it. As soon as there is a need to call
  mobile app from web server send a push notification. Handle the push
  notification on application side to make a call to web api as soon as
  it receives the push notification with specific payload.
- Use Web Sockets if server events are too frequent.